# how to convert string array JSON to be ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

so I have this JSON in string format:

```
[
  "1.0",
  "1.1",
  "1.2"
]
```

but I need to convert it to ArrayList In Kotlin ? I have tried to find, but most of the answer are in Java. if using gson in Java maybe it will be like this. but I am a beginner and I failed to convert the code below to Kotlin

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ArrayList<String> theList = gson.fromJson(stringObject, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType())
```

what should I do to convert that json string to array list in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe this is the kotlin code you want, converted from your Java code:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val theList = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<String>>(stringObject, object :TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.type)
```